# How to detect camera is opened or running from a service

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm working on a music player app. I need how to detect when the camera app is running. I searched a lot without success.

I guess there should be an intent for that, like detecting incoming phone calls, or headphone plugged/unplugged, something like that, so that I can register a broadcast receiver to listen the camera broadcast intent:

```
registerReceiver(new IntentFilter(HERE SOME CAMERA OPENING INTENT))
```

I found how to detect the camera button (CAMERA_BUTTON intent) and the image capture (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent), but not the camera open event.

The app is running a service, so the broadcast receiver will be there to pause the music.

Please, don't ask why (honestly, I'm wondering the same thing). Is not optional, sorry.

Thanks!

btw, sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not believe such an intent is broadcast to signify that the Camera application has launched.

If that is true then you won't be able to use a broadcast receiver to listen for this.

If you hope to detect this you'd need a service that would have to be continually reading all the Log outputs and looking for the "Starting Activity com.blah.blah.camera" entry that gets fired when the camera is launched.